# UTF-8 Encoding not work on Outlook incoming messages

Tags: php, utf-8, outlook, character-encoding, html-email

This is my mail template:

```
$body='<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Transactional Email</title>'; 
$body.='<p>Solicitor’s Certificates - Tips & Traps</p>';
$body.='</head></html>';
```

I sent this email using PHP mail library.
The mail body `Solicitor’s Certificates - Tips & Traps` appears correctly on each browsers and most of email clients. But dose not in Microsoft Outlook.
In outlook it shows as `Solicitorâ€™s Certificates - Tips & Traps`.
Is there a way to resolve this, I tried most of the ways that mentions in the internet. But they haven't resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve the issue defining CharSet to PHPMailer by myself.

```
$php_mail = new PHPMailer;
$php_mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Comment: Why haven't you provided this detail in your example right away? "_PHP mail library_" can mean so many software in many different versions. You want others to reproduce your problem, so write a minimal but **full** example.